# The total energy of an atomic supercell with a local dipole moment in an external electric field

Tags: condensed-matter, electric-fields

How to define the total energy of an atomic supercell with a local dipole moment in an external electric field?

The figure below illustrates the two cases of the local dipole moment within an atomic supercell, where the dipole moment in **a** is anti-parallel to the external electric field, while the dipole moment in **b** is parallel to the external electric field.

[image: illus]

Intuitively, I think the system in **b** has a lower total energy, i.e., $E_{\text{atomic supercell}}$ + $E_{\text{dipole in external field}}$, but I don't know how to calculate $E_{\text{dipole in external field}}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment#Energy_and_torque